# Java Gui components do not appear in the JFrame

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, components

i have a strange problem which may a problem with eclipse that i use:

i want to programm a calculator but the components which should appear in the Jframe, are not there! The textfield do not appears until i click on it and the button come out when i go over it with the mouse pointer...

here's my code:

```
package calculator;

import java.awt.Font;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JButton;

public class MeinTaschenrechner extends JFrame {

    JTextField textField;
    JButton button1;

    public MeinTaschenrechner() {

        setVisible(true);
        setSize(300, 300);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setTitle("Taschenrechner");
        setResizable(false);
        setLayout(null);


        textField=new JTextField("0");
        textField.setBounds(5, 10, 285, 50);
        Font font=textField.getFont().deriveFont(Font.PLAIN,30);
        textField.setFont(font);
        add(textField);
//      addingNumberButtons();
        button1=new JButton("1");
        button1.setBounds(5, 65, 75, 65);
        add(button1);
    }
```

And here is my main class:

```
package calculator;

public class ExecuteKlasse {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        MeinTaschenrechner cc=new MeinTaschenrechner();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot make setVisible(true); your first line of code. Add setVisible(true); as the last line in your constructor.

Comment: perfect! what is the problem if it is the first line?

Comment: If it's the first line then your components with whatever state they are in start to get drawn. Other's you construct wont appear until the next repaint, which can happen for many reasons, such as if you stretch the window, or rollover your mouse over special rollover areas if the components have them like you did with your button.

Comment: @user3133542, You need to add the components to the frame BEFORE you make it visible. Also, don't use setBounds(). Swing was designed to be used with layout managers.